# Reading a data from error.yml and while storing in a map, it returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, yaml

I have to read the data from the error.yml file and store it in a below-structured map. While using the below configuration to store the values, I am getting null. Could someone please help me with this? Thanks!

Configuration class:

> @Configuration @PropertySource(value = "classpath:error.yml ", factory
> = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class) @EnableConfigurationProperties @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "errorcodes") @Getter @Slf4j
> @ConstructorBinding public class ErrorService {
>
> private  Map<String, ApiError> errors = new HashMap<>();
>
> .... }

error.yml:
errorcodes:
errors:
ERROR_1:
code: 1
message: Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

You can have a configuration like below and build the object using values from your yaml file.

```
@Configuration
public class YourConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "errors")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "errorcodes")
    public Map<String,Object> errors() { return new HashMap<>() };
    ...
}
```

You can autowire the configuration class where you need it and get 'errors' from the autowired instance.

```
public class SomeOtherClass {
    ...
    @Autowired
    YourConfiguration yourConfiguration;
    ...
    ...
    public <T> someMethod() {
       Map<String,Object> errorsFromYaml = yourConfiguration.errors();
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```